# Update redux form field from a callback

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I'm trying to do this:

```
"redux-form": "6.0.0-rc.5", 
"react": "^15.3.1",
"react-dom": "^15.3.1",




addressUpdated(newAddress) {
    //TODO, tell Redux form that a value is now available!
    this.props.fields.address.onChange(newAddress.label);
}
```

**address** is a hidden field that should get a value once addressUpdated is called.
I get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onChange' of undefined
```

Component is generated:

```
<Field id="address" name="address" type="hidden" component={fieldFactory} />



const fieldFactory = ({id, input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => {
    if(type.match(/hidden/)){
        return(
            <div>
                <input id={id} {...input} type={type} />
                {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can no longer use *fields* in props with v6.

Consider row-form.js:

```
Row.propTypes = {
  change: PropTypes.func.isRequired, // this binds redux-form change action creator
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

then your callback function would look like this:

```
addressUpdated(newAddress) {
    this.props.dispatch(this.props.change('address', newAddress.label);
}
```

Beware that in v6 rc5 this is not working because of the [bug](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1579), but it was fixed in 6.0.1.

In order to get that to work in rc5 you should import global change action creator and dispatch it with your form name:

```
import { change } from 'redux-form';

Row.propTypes = {
  form: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

addressUpdated(newAddress) {
   this.props.dispatch(change(this.props.form, 'address', newAddress.label);
}
```

API reference: http://redux-form.com/6.0.1/docs/api/Props.md/

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!